# matlab brute force indexing

Tags: matlab, for-loop, brute-force

Hi I am working with the brute force method to examine possible combinations of "panels" and "turbines"

My code is

```
 for number_panels = 0:5

for number_turbines = 0:10


    for n = 1:24 % number of hours per day



deficit(n) = Demand(n) - (PV_supply(n)*number_panels) -...
 (WT_supply(n)*number_turbines);% hourly power deficit

        if deficit(n)<0

            deficit(n) = 0;

        end
```

The problem I have above is that I haven't yet figured the correct indexing of this code.

What I am trying to do is find the "deficit" for the "number_panels" , "number_turbines" and "n". As it stands I can only find the "deficit" for the last for loop. 
How can I code so that I can have the option to access the nth row (or sets of "n" i.e 1-24) and also for the "number_panels" "number_turbines" option?

---

thanks - in order to find the sum of each deficit(n) value and thus have the respective total deficit of the 24 hour period I have done the following which seems to me to be able to do what I am asking but I am getting incorrect answers:

```
 daily_deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1) =...
 sum(deficit(number_panels + 1, number_turbines + 1,n)) –
```

Comment: If you post a syntactically correct piece of Matlab some of us will cut and paste it and see if we can run it and figure out your problem.  What you have posted is not syntactically correct. I'm probably not the only SOer too idle to make basic corrections to your code in the interests of helping you.  Do yourself a favour, make those corrections yourself.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice though Im not quite sure what the problem is. Apart from stating the size of Demand, PV_supply and WT_supply which are 24x1 what else is required in terms of info? and what are the problems to what I have shown above?

Comment: I am a beginner so I definitely need all the advice/guidance I can get. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function calcDeficit.m:

```
File Edit Options Buffers Tools ObjC Help                                                                              
function deficit = calcDeficit (Demand, PV_supply, WT_supply)

  % initialize the size (good practice)
  deficit = zeros(6,11,24);


  for number_panels = 0:5

    for number_turbines = 0:10

      for n = 1:24 % number of hours per day
        deficit(number_panels+1,number_turbines+1,:) = Demand(n) - (PV_supply(n)*number_panels) -...
          (WT_supply(n)*number_turbines);% hourly power deficit

        if deficit(n)<0 
          deficit(n) = 0;
        end
      end
    end
  end
return
```

example call:

```
Demand=randn(24,1); PV_supply=randn(24,1); WT_supply=randn(24,1); test(Demand,PV_supply,WT_supply)
```

You access Demand by

```
Demand(panels+1,number_turbines+1,hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're storing the `deficit` result as a function only of the value `n`, the number of hours per day. In your inner loop around `n`, you keep replacing the values each time through your outer loops, so at the end of the run, you only have the value for `n = 1:24` at `number_panels` = 5 and `number_turbines` = 10.

Try this:

```
deficit(number_panels+1, number_turbines+1, n) = ...
```

That way at the end, you can check any combination given the three indices. I've added a value of 1 to number_panels and number_turbines because MATLAB uses 1-based indexes. To get your results for a specific number of panels or turbines, make sure to add 1 when checking.

Specifically, for 3 panels and 4 turbines at hour 5 in the day:

`disp(deficit(3+1, 4+1, 5))`

**EDIT**: Added 1 to the values of `number_panels` and `number_turbines` to avoid 0-indexing.